# error is occured by delete function (django fbv)

Tags: django

I ran the deletion with the following function

Deletion is succeeded but error occurred

```
def todo_delete (request, pk):
    # template = 'todo / todo_confirm_delete.html'
    todo = get_object_or_404 (Todo, pk = pk)
    todo.delete ()
    Profile.objects.filter (Q (user = request.user.id)). Update (uncompletecount = F ('uncompletecount') - 1)
    print ("todo", todo, delete ')

    return reverse_lazy ('todo: todo_list')
```

error

```
 AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'
```

this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error this is error

error

```
(venv) (base) C:\django_inflearn2>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 30, 2019 - 14:28:12
Django version 2.2, using settings 'reservation_app.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[30/May/2019 14:28:12] "GET /todo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15022
[30/May/2019 14:28:12] "GET /summernote/editor/id_text/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6349
[30/May/2019 14:28:12] "GET /static/summernote/lang/summernote-en-US.min.js?_=1559194092912 HTTP/1.1" 200 27

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hyunsepk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 141, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence
[30/May/2019 14:28:17] "GET /todo/60/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

thanks for let me know what is reason for error and how to fix

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: thanks for concern I include full error code

Comment: @HyK I think the issue is with your `view` returning a `url` instead of a `response` or `redirect`

Comment: @HyK am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view `todo_delete` is expecting a html response and you are returning a `url`.

I believe the purpose of

```
return reverse_lazy ('todo: todo_list')
```

is to redirect to some `todo_list` page.

try to use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
return redirect(reverse_lazy ('todo: todo_list'))
```

You got the idea. I haven't tested the code but I believe you will understand.